# Problem with Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a simple expression

```
-1 + P[1] + a[1] P[1] + P[2] + a[2] P[2] + P[3] + a[3] P[3]
```

Where

```
P[1] + P[2] + P[3] == 1
```

so the desired result would be

```
a[1] P[1] + a[2] P[2] + a[3] P[3].
```

I tried

```
Simplify[-1 + P[1] + a[1] P[1] + P[2] + a[2] P[2] + P[3] + a[3] P[3], P[1] + P[2] + P[3] == 1]
```

to no effect.

The very disagreeable

```
(-1 + P[1] + a[1] P[1] + P[2] + a[2] P[2] + P[3] + a[3] P[3]) /. (P[1] + P[2] + P[3])->1
```

does work.

The problem is I want to be able to extend this such that a result like

```
-1 + P[1] + a[1] P[1] + P[2] + a[2] P[2] + P[3] + a[3] P[3] + P[4] + a[4] P[4] + P[5] + a[5] P[5]
```

Where

```
P[1] + P[2] + P[3] + P[4] + P[5] == 1
```

Will simplify as well.

Comment: `PolynomialReduce` will do the sort of thing you want. The problem is that it does not always give the particular representative (of all the equivalent answer) you seek.

Comment: @MichaelE2 How would PolynomialReduce be applied?

Comment: Something like this: `Last@PolynomialReduce[-1 + P[1] + a[1] P[1] + P[2] + a[2] P[2] + P[3] + a[3] P[3], {P[1] + P[2] + P[3] - 1}, {P[3], P[1], P[2]}]`. The second input argument is a list of polynomial expressions equivalent to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you found using `ReplaceAll` "very disagreeable", so you might not like this either, but it works for any number of indexed terms in any variable.

```
SetAttributes[specialXform, HoldAll]
specialXform[expr_, var_, n_] :=
  (Unevaluated @ expr /. -1 -> -Plus @@ Table[Unevaluated @ var[i], {i, n}])

specialXform[-1 + P[1] + a[1] P[1] + P[2] + a[2] P[2] + P[3] + a[3] P[3], P, 3]
```

> `a[1] P[1] + a[2] P[2] + a[3] P[3]`

```
specialXform[-1 + q[1] + a q[1] + q[2] + b q[2]^2, q, 2]
```

> `a q[1] + b q[2]^2`

Comment: Yes, this would work with any number of indexed variables.